# "Ever since I was a kid playing football, to my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I have always been a huge Messi fan."

Tags: sentence-construction

> Ever since I was a kid playing football, to my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I have always been a huge Messi fan.

Can I use 'ever since' and 'to' like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine.  Literally it means that you stopped being a Messi fan after the meeting. But I don't think anyone would understand it like that.

If you want to avoid that interpretation then remove the "to..." phrase. And put the information in a separate sentence.

> Ever since I was a kid playing football I have always been a huge Messi fan. Recently I met Lionel Messi, and ...

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's incorrect, because *since* means *from then until now,* but if the sentence is used in informal speech, listeners understand that the speaker has 'changed course' mid-sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. @James K gives the reason in his answer, although he says no-one would understand it like that. I disagree. Some people *would* misunderstand.

Your sentence implies that you were a fan for most of your life but when you finally met your hero *something changed*. Maybe he was rude to you and you stopped being a fan or maybe he was good to you and you became even more of a fan.

So, regardless of what people might understand, your English is wrong - unless of course you did stop being a fan when you met him!

One way to correct this out of many is to make it clear that you are still a fan, as follows:

*Ever since I was a kid playing football, to my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I have always been and still am a huge Messi fan.*

Answer (score 0):

> Ever since I was a kid playing football, **[to](https://www.lexico.com/definition/to) <sup>1.2</sup>** my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I have always been a huge Messi fan.

In order to suggest that they *stopped* being a fan of Lionel Messi, the last clause needs to be in the past perfect tense. I'd also suggest changing *to* with *until*, this neatly avoids any confusion

> Ever since…, **[until](http://https:/https://www.lexico.com/definition/until)** my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I ***had always been*** a huge Messi fan.

If the speaker continues to be a fan, then the preposition in the parenthetical clause should be changed.

> Ever since I was a kid playing football, even **[after](https://www.lexico.com/definition/after)** my recent meeting with Lionel Messi, I have always been a huge Messi fan.